# How can I get value from radio button

Tags: javascript

In my code I want to get the clicked value from radio button when I click one or more radio button it get the value and store in array. any idea how can I do it using javascript

```js
var myArray = ["Asian", "Thai", "Korean", "Chinese", "Mexican"];

var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

var elementsToInsert = [];

// Creation of the input with radio type and the labels
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var radio = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  radio.type = 'radio';
  radio.name = myArray[i];
  radio.value = myArray[i];

  label.setAttribute("for", myArray[i]);
  label.innerHTML = myArray[i];

  elementsToInsert.push({ label: label, radio: radio });
}

// Insert the labels and input in a random order
while(elementsToInsert.length !== 0) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementsToInsert.length);

  // Array.prototype.splice removes items from the Array and return the an array containing the removed items (See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)
  var toInsert = elementsToInsert.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
wrapper.appendChild(toInsert.radio);
  wrapper.appendChild(toInsert.label);
  wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: please check first by this condition is this statisfied then document.getElementById('radioButton').checked

you can get value by
document.getElementById('radioButton').value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function on `onclick` event listener to the input element that you have created, this will get you what you have clicked

Example

```
var myArray = ["Asian", "Thai", "Korean", "Chinese", "Mexican"];

var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

var elementsToInsert = [];

var output = [];

function handleClick(e) { // function defined
output.push(e.target.value)
console.log(output)
}

// Creation of the input with radio type and the labels
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var radio = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  radio.type = 'radio';
  radio.name = myArray[i];
  radio.value = myArray[i];
  radio.onclick = handleClick; // function added
  

  label.setAttribute("for", myArray[i]);
  label.innerHTML = myArray[i];

  elementsToInsert.push({ label: label, radio: radio });
}

// Insert the labels and input in a random order
while(elementsToInsert.length !== 0) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementsToInsert.length);

  // Array.prototype.splice removes items from the Array and return the an array containing the removed items (See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)
  var toInsert = elementsToInsert.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
    wrapper.appendChild(toInsert.radio);
  wrapper.appendChild(toInsert.label);
  wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  
}
```